# SQL Server 2012: Insert into temp table static values, results of Stored Procedures and calculated value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

I have multiple `stored procedures` which return a value. I want to create another `stored procedure` which will run all of the existing `SPs` and store the returned values in a `temp table`:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptbl(metricid int, value float, normalizedvalue int)
```

Where the `metricid` will be static, for example to `SP_CalcMetric1` will be 1 etc.

`value` will be the return result of each `SP`

`normalizedvalue` will be a normalized value of the returned result of each `SP`, which will be normalized for example for `SP_CalcMetric1`

```
if (value < 5)
     normalizedvalue = 100;
else if (value >= 5 && value < 10)
     normalizedvalue = 50;
else
     normalizedvalue = 0;
```

Each `SP` result has a different normalization method.

The question is how I can write the `insert statement` to combine the static int, the value of the Stored Procedure and the normalized value (calculated from the normalize method)

Comment: It's not clear what bit you have trouble with. Capturing the return values of each SP? (`EXEC @retval = SP_CalcMetric1 ...`) Writing the `INSERT` statements? Translating your pseudo-code into T-SQL? Doing this for a variable number of procedures?

Comment: What is your question here exactly? You don't appear to have asked one.

Comment: Please check edited question

Comment: How many stored procedures like `SP_CalcMetric1` do you have?

Comment: @Brian 18 Stored Procedures

Comment: Any chance you could just have `CalcMetric`, taking a `@metricid` parameter? That would at least make your outer logic more robust, as otherwise you'll need dynamic SQL. (But if each of those procedures has wildly different logic, then it doesn't help much, as it just shifts the complexity to the stored procedure which has to `CASE` or `IF`.) (Also, [don't use the `sp_` prefix for user stored procedures](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix), it's reserved *and* bad for performance.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert No each `SP` calculates totally different things

Comment: How do the stored procedures return their results? Do they return their result(s) as rows in a result set (`SELECT <value>`) and can there be more than one row? Or are you using the return value of the stored procedure (that is, `RETURN <value>`? These approaches require different ways of processing. (In general, using the return value for anything other than an error condition is not advisable, since it can only ever be a non-`NULL` `INT`.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert It returns as row in a result set (`select from #temptable`) and its always a single row

Answer (score 1):

You can use OPENQUERY to manipulate the values returned by sp call and insert results from each sp separately into the same table, something like...

```
CREATE TABLE #temptbl(metricid int, value float, normalizedvalue int);

INSERT INTO #temptbl(metricid , value  , normalizedvalue )
SELECT  1 
      , value
      ,  CASE 
            WHEN value < 5 
                THEN 100
            WHEN value >= 5 AND value < 10
                THEN 50
            ELSE 0
        END
FROM OPENQUERY(YOURSERVERNAME, 'EXEC SP_CalcMetric1')

UNION ALL 

SELECT  2 
      , value
      ,  CASE    --<-- Some other logic here as you mentioned it could be different
            WHEN value < 5     
                THEN 100
            WHEN value >= 5 AND value < 10
                THEN 50
            ELSE 0
        END
FROM OPENQUERY(YOURSERVERNAME, 'EXEC SP_CalcMetric2')
.
.
. add more union all if you need to.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change each `CalcMetric` procedure to return three values:

```
MetricID
Value
NormalizedValue  (this can be encapsulated in a scalar-value function)
```

(and rename it as Jeroen Mostert suggested in the comments)

Then you just insert the results of the stored procedure into #TempTBL